# Cron jobs on flexible appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-flexible

I have multiple cron jobs configured on flexible appengine to execute once a day with max retry of 5 times. Is there a way send alert after last retry fails? If I need to do this in my code, does cron provides any information that allows me to determine current retry count?

Comment: Cron job does not have "max retry" param, taskqueue does.

Answer (score 0):

@marcadian - The cron.yaml reference here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cronref#retry shows that you can set job_retry_limit in the retry_parameters block of the cron.yaml

Comment: oh, i was not aware about that. Thank you! maybe I haven't opened the doc for a very long time lol